# Go Profiling - Wrong file

Tags: go, profiling, pprof

I'm doing profiling in Go using github.com/pkg/profile and it's creating the file when I run my code, but the return comes from the example page code, how would it be to run through my code?
thanks in advance

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pkg/profile"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    defer profile.Start(profile.MemProfile).Stop()

    var inicio = time.Now().UnixNano()

    var text = "Olá Mundo!"

    fmt.Println(text)

    var fim = time.Now().UnixNano()

    fmt.Println(fim - inicio)

}
```

Return:

[image]

Comment: you need to do something, where in you need to do something much more practical, profiler is not getting enough samples(enough time) to acquire any data.

Comment: @nilsocket but even in the most complex examples the result is this

Comment: @nilsocket how would you see the memory consuption of all?

Comment: `pkg/profile` outputs the profiling file to `/tmp` directory, are you opening that file? If so then may be you are not allocating enough memory to actually look at something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your profile output path to to your current working directory,

```
profile.ProfilePath(path)
```

If you are unable to make retrieve any samples, it either means your `MemProfileRate` is not small enough to actually capture small changes.

If you are allocation less amount of memory, then set the `MemProfileRate` to lesser value, If you are allocating large amount of memory, just keep to default. If you think you capturing minor memory changes, then increase the `MemProfileRate`.

```
profile.MemProfileRate(100)
```

and one thing you shouldn't forget when you are using `profile` package is your call should be deferred.

```
defer profile.Start(xxx).Stop()
```

Here is the complete program.

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/pkg/profile"
)

func main() {
    dir, _ := os.Getwd()
    defer profile.Start(profile.MemProfile, profile.MemProfileRate(100), profile.ProfilePath(dir)).Stop()
    //decrease mem profile rate for capturing more samples
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        tmp := make([]byte, 100000)
        tmp[0] = tmp[1] << 0 //fake workload
    }
}
```

you can also set profile path for having the profile output in your current workign directory.